# What was the Kobayashi Maru doing in Klingon Space?

Tags: star-trek

So my understanding is that a Civilian Freighter was flying around the Klingon Neutral Zone, hit a gravitic mine, and got stranded.

But my question is **If the Klingon Neutral Zone is somewhere ships are banned from travelling, what was the Kobayashi Maru doing there in the first place?**

The freighter didn't lose power and drift into the the Neutral Zone, it was already in the Neutral Zone when it was stranded. This seems highly suspicious to me, like it was a Klingon trap or a group of Smugglers who got caught.

Is there a canon explanation as to why the Kobayashi Maru was in the Neutral Zone in the first place?

Comment: ["Presumably, the scenario was modified, over time, to fit current events in the galaxy. For instance, Kirk's simulation could not have included the element of the Klingon Neutral Zone, as it was established years later – in the Treaty of Organia in 2267."](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru_scenario)

Comment: Is it ever established that "ships are banned from travelling" in the Neutral Zone? Or is it only *military* vessels (or other government vessels, if you don't want to call Starfleet "military")? The *Kobayashi Maru* is, as you say, called a "civilian freighter". And Star Trek V has a "peace planet" in the (a?) neutral zone that people and supplies have to get to somehow.

Comment: Point of order: I don't think that the ship actually hit a *land* mine.

Comment: @Steve-O  Of course it wasn't a land mine, it was a space mine.   So how do you hide a mine in outer space where you can't cover it with dirt or seawater?  Why wouldn't the sensors detect a space mine nearby?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes you say that the freighter didn't drift into the neutral zone?

Comment: @HarryJohnston https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru#Simulation "the cadet receives a distress signal stating that the civilian freighter Kobayashi Maru has struck a gravitic mine in the Klingon Neutral Zone"

Comment: There's no citation and the [scene in question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6tWmSckE40) doesn't make it clear either way IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In primary canon, the [*Kobayashi Maru*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru)'s "real-life" inspiration has never been detailed.

In extended canon, a [novel](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru_(novel)) bearing the same name as the ship reveals that the original scenario takes place during the lead-up to the [Earth-Romulan War](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-Romulan_War). At the time, the Romulans had been

> using a "telecapture device" to remotely hijack enemy vessels for various skullduggery. The [*Maru*](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/ECS_Kobayashi_Maru) was struck by a gravitic mine en route to making a run to a secret Vulcan listening post near Romulan space, carrying supplies and 300 passengers to staff the post. This incident was engineered by the Romulans to lure the NX-01 *Enterprise* into range of the telecapture device. The *Enterprise* was provided with a warning of the trap, leaving Archer with a no-win scenario: attempt a rescue with significant risk of losing his ship to the enemy, or allow the *Maru*, its passengers and crew to perish.